# The browser attempt to download php pages instead of open it

Tags: php, ubuntu

in my project I have a php page, when I try to open it from the browser (Chrome or Firefox) it attempts to download it instead of open.
I've tried to open from the smartphone and it works correctly.

I have Linux Mint (Distro based on ubuntu) and php it's installed and I've tried to run following commands (read from a similar question)

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo a2enmod php5
```

But libapache2-mod-php5 it's installed and php it's already enabled.

Update:
I think this is a ubuntu problem because I've restarted my pc and logged in with windows and here it works!

Comment: Is your php server running?

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: I have another project which contains php file and it works correctly. I have this problem for a week, I don't think this could be solve by restarting apache

Comment: When *some* Browsers / OSes open the page correctly there should not be a problem with the php installation. You should add more details about the expected page output to your question, maybe ubuntu is missing a plugin or the page has the wrong document type identifier (`Content-Type`).

Comment: when you download the file, is it php script, or it is processed with php already

Answer (score 0):

Install LAMP and try it again. You can easily install LAMP by installing tasksel. 
First install tasksel.
then install LAMP.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel